# how to clean redundant threads in ColdFusion

Tags: multithreading, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Is there a way of telling which threads are redundant and remove them?

Is this something that might need to be done? or do threads self terminate if they encounter any error or are used for too long?

Comment: I thought threads self terminate when they were finished.

Comment: I can't tell with absolute certainty whether that is the case...

Answer (score 1):

You can control the number of available threads in the ColdFusion Administrator under **"Server Settings > Request Tuning > Maximum number of simultaneous Template requests"** will set the number of available workers/threads ready to accept requests handed off from the webserver. You can fine tune some of the other thread settings (direct CFC/Remoting requests, report requests etc) there as well. The thread pool should recycle itself normally if it encounters a ColdFusion error but there are "hung" threads.

The thread pool should stay at the number set in the administrator.  You can set a timeout on a thread's maximum runtime under **"Server Settings > Settings > Timeout Requests after seconds"** setting.

Using the built-in server monitor under **Server Monitoring > Server Monitor** You can go to Alerts -> Alert Configuration and set a number of thread killing conditions based on timeouts, memory, etc. but this does increase the load on your system.

This section of the [Performance tuning for ColdFusion applications](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/coldfusion_performance.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_0) article from Adobe gives you some tips/advice about threads.

[Fusion Reactor](http://www.fusion-reactor.com/fr/) is a great commercial product for those who need powerful control for high-availability over their ColdFusion server.

Also checkout [CFTracker](http://www.cftracker.net/), a free/OSS CF Server Monitoring Project.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the active threads and kill them. Go through the link below.

http://coldfusion-tip.blogspot.com/search/label/thread%20kill